# Can I start AirPlay automatically?

Tags: macos, airplay

My Macbook is without a screen as the connector broke. There's a way to start AirPlay automatically on startup so I can watch on my AppleTV or any script I can use to start the AirPlay?

Comment: Why not plug in a monitor to the display port on your MBP?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to start AirPlay automatically on startup or use a script to start AirPlay.

To start AirPlay automatically on startup, you can follow these steps:

1. Connect your MacBook to your Apple TV using an HDMI cable.
2. Turn on your Apple TV and your MacBook.
3. Go to **Apple menu** > **System Preferences** > **Displays** > **Arrangement**, check the box that says **Mirror Displays**.
4. Close the Displays preferences window.

You can also add the AppleScript application to your startup items to automatically start AirPlay whenever you log in to your MacBook. To do this:

1. Go to **Apple menu** > **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups**
2. Click on your username in the left sidebar.
3. Click on the **Login Items** tab.
4. Click on the "**+**" button to add the AppleScript application to the list of startup items.

Now, whenever you log in to your MacBook, the AppleScript application will automatically run and start AirPlay.

Comment: The instructions are just manual steps, and the answer doesn't provide any AppleScript...

Comment: How would you perform these steps on a Macbook without a working screen?